# Convert a list to dataframe with headers

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a question
I have a list

```
list=['nick', 'george', 'kate']
```

Is it possible to convert it into a dataframe with headers the names of the list ? ('nick' etc.)
probably it's easy but I am a beginner so I struggle a little bit thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Code

```
import pandas as pd

list = ['nick', 'george', 'kate']

df = pd.DataFrame(list, columns =['name'])

print(df)
```

#### Output

```
     name
0    nick
1  george
2    kate
```